# Calculating costs for an API on the basis of server load and storage

Tags: usage

We're going to release a commercial API product very soon.

The API provides the ability to upload, covert and store different media formats. Uploaded files will be converted to open and closed media formats.

What's the best method to calculate a price for the different kinds of API Request Types like Video and Sound on the basis of the storage, traffic, load costs?

Answer (score 1):

how much it costs you to service a request + how much profit you want per request

Comment: How should I calculate the costs of a load spike on the server, when a audio- or media is converted?

Comment: You can't. You can however implement a queue system if you want to be in complete control of costs.